Randomize Occurrence Date by Series Id while keeping the order of dates
I am randomizing data for a test database. The requirement is: For every row in Record table, randomize the day and month of Occurrence Date, which is a date column. If the row belongs to a group of more than one RecordSeriesId, keep the order of the Occurrence Dates, but randomize the day and month. The end result should look like as below after randomizing sans the Row ID which is there for your information, with the year being the same year as the original. The table has a INT incremental unique identifier.
My issue is with randomizing the day and month while keeping the year as well as maintaining the actual order of the records. I need a script to go through the entire table and update to randomize the days and months, but maintain the OccurrenceDate order for records with the same RecordSeriesId, with later records in the series still being after previous occurrence dates and keeping its year.



OccurrenceDate
RecordSeriesId




2019-04-30 ( Row ID 2044 )
3911


2019-05-05 ( Row ID 2054 )
3911


2020-03-12 ( Row ID 2056 )
3911


2020-07-15 ( Row ID 2099 )
3911



The farthest I have gotten is randomizing dates in the same year as the original occurrence date, but this does not account for previous rows in the series, and I do not know how to go about solving this problem.
WITH RandomizedDates AS (
  SELECT Id,
    RecordSeriesId,
    OccurrenceDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordSeriesId ORDER BY OccurrenceDate) AS RowNumber,
    DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 30, DATEADD(MONTH, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 12, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(OccurrenceDate), 1, 1))) AS RandomizedDate
  FROM 
    Record
)
SELECT Id,
  RecordSeriesId,
  RandomizedDate
FROM 
  RandomizedDates
ORDER BY 
  RecordSeriesId,
  RandomizedDate;


You can subtract from the current date a random fraction of the time between it and the previous date - using LAG with default the current date truncated to the YEAR - over the partition by RecordSeriesId order by RowId.
